# How can i figure out a max_user_connections on ASP.NET | MySql application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, ado.net

last year i developed an ASP.NET Application implenting MVP Model.
The site is not very large  (about 9.000 views/day).
It is a common application witch just desplays articles, supports scheduling (via datetime),vote and views, sections and categories.

From then i create more than 15 sites with the same motive ( The database michanism was build in the same logic).

What i did was : 
Every time a request arrive i have to take articles, sections, categories, views and votes from my Database and display them to the user...like all other web apps.

My database objects are somthing like the above :

```
public class MyObjectDatabaseManager{
       public static string Table = DBTables.ArticlesTable;
       public static string ConnectionString = ApplicationManager.ConnectionString;
       public bool insertMyObject(MyObject myObject){/*.....*/}
       public bool updateMyObject(MyObject myObject){/*.....*/}
       public bool deleteMyObject(MyObject myObject){/*.....*/}
       public MyObject getMyObject(int MyObjectID){/**/}
       public List<MyObject> getMyObjects( int limit, int page, bool OrderBy, bool ASC){/*...*/}
}
```

When ever i want to communicate to the database i do something like the above

```
   MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
   try
      {
       myConnection.Open();
       MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(myQuery,myConnection);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(...);
       cmd.ExecuteReader(); /* OR */ ExecuteNonQuery();
   }catch(Exception){}
   finally
    {
        if (myConnection != null)
        {
            myConnection.Close();
            myConnection.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Two months later i've run into trouble.

The performance start falling down and the database starts to return errors : max_user_connections

Then i think.. " Let's cache the page "
And the start to use Output cache for the pages.
(not a very sophisticated good idea..)

12 months later my friend told to me to create a "live" article...
an article that can be updated without any delay. (from the output cache...)

Then it came into my mind that : " Why to use cache? joomla etc **doesn't"

So...i remove the magic "Output cache" directive...
From then i run again into the same problem...
MAX_USER_CONNETCTIONS! :/

What i'm doing wrong?

I know that my code communicates alot with the database but...
the connection pooling?

**Sorry for my english**

Please...help :/
i have no idea how to figure it out:/

Thank you.
*I'm running into share hosting packet*
*My db is over 60mb in size*
*I have more than 6000 rows in some tables like articles*
*My hosting provider gives me 25 connections to the database (very large number in my opinion)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me, although from a style perspective I prefer "using" to "try / finally / Dispose()".

One thing to check is to make sure that the connection strings you're using are identical, everywhere in your code. Most DB drivers to connection pooling based on comparing the connection strings.

You may need to increase the max_connections variable in your mysql config.

See:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html

Comment: Sorry for the delay but i solve the problem using again output cache.
i think that max-user-connection problem was that i run a query based on a field witch i haven't index. using order by...then if i have 25 requests on same time the mysql server was anable to reply. 25*2.5sec ~= 62.5 sec for those requests...and so on.
That's why i have the problem.
Thank you:)

Answer (score -1):

Actually, Max #/connections is an OS-level configuration.

For example, under NT/XP, it was configurable in the registry, under HKLM, ..., TcpIp, Parameters, TcpNumConnections:

http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html

More important, you want to maximum the number of "ephemeral ports" needed to open new connections:

http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ephemeral_ports.html

- Windows:

  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
  On the Edit menu, click Add Value, and then add the following registry value:

  Value Name: MaxUserPort Data Type: REG_DWORD Value: 65534
- Linux:

  sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="1024 64000"

Comment: Yes but i run into 2 problems us i say : First i think that my code isn't very sofisticated. Second i think that 25 connections is a large number (dispite i can't change it because i'm running on share host)

Comment: Thank you but again i can't figure out why this is happening into my project and when i run from another CMS like joomla(witch i hate it btw) with 15000 articles doesn't display any error message?